# More than 32 links in LinkLabel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linklabel, overflowexception

I'm currently making an app in C# which make use of `LinkLabels`. I have a function that add a new link for each element in a certain array. However, it happens that the array have more than 32 links, and when that happens, I receive an OverflowException:

> System.OverflowException: Overflow error.
>          at System.Drawing.StringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(CharacterRange[] ranges)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.CreateStringFormat()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.EnsureRun(Graphics g)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Is there a way to override the `SetMeasurableCharacterRanges` function. So that it doesn't throw that error when having more than 32 character ranges?
Here is a sample of my code:

```
int LengthCounter = 0;
llbl.Links.Clear();
string[] props = AList.ToArray();

llbl.Text = string.Join(", ", props);
foreach (var Prop in props)
{
    llbl.Links.Add(LengthCounter, Prop.Length, string.Format("{0}{1}", prefix, Sanitize(Prop)));
    LengthCounter += Prop.Length + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetMeasurableCharacterRanges` is implemented like this:

```
/// <summary>Specifies an array of <see cref="T:System.Drawing.CharacterRange" /> structures that represent the ranges of characters measured by a call to the <see cref="M:System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(System.String,System.Drawing.Font,System.Drawing.RectangleF,System.Drawing.StringFormat)" /> method.</summary>
/// <param name="ranges">An array of <see cref="T:System.Drawing.CharacterRange" /> structures that specifies the ranges of characters measured by a call to the <see cref="M:System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(System.String,System.Drawing.Font,System.Drawing.RectangleF,System.Drawing.StringFormat)" /> method.</param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.OverflowException">More than 32 character ranges are set.</exception>
public void SetMeasurableCharacterRanges( CharacterRange[] ranges )
{
    int num = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipSetStringFormatMeasurableCharacterRanges( new HandleRef( this, this.nativeFormat ), ranges.Length, ranges );
    if( num != 0 )
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException( num );
}
```

The class `StringFormat` is sealed and the method `SetMeasurableCharacterRanges` is not virtual, so you **cannot override** it. And internally it does an API call to `gdiplus.dll`.

What you can try is to inherit a **custom LinkLabel** from `LinkLabel` and override `OnPaint()`-method and do drawing complety by your own. (Things would be easier if method `CreateStringFormat()` was not internal.)

Or you just use **multiple LinkLabels** on a `FlowLayoutPanel` with only one link per label:

```
for( int i = 0; i < AList.Count; i++ )
{
    string prop = AList[i];
    LinkLabel llbl = new LinkLabel()
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        Margin = new Padding( 0 ),
        Name = "llbl" + i,
        Text = prop + ", "
    };
    llbl.Links.Add( 0, prop.Length, string.Format( "{0}{1}", prefix, Sanitize( prop ) ) );

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add( llbl );
}
```